# Can We Use Modal Verbs Could / would for future events?

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs

Can We Use Modal Verbs for future events?

My examples are as follows,

Could:

Can you tell me how could we recover this amount from him in the next month?

Would:

Can you tell me would it be possible us to recover this amount from him in the next month?

Might:

We might recover this amount from him in his next months salary.

In my above examples I want to mention that Money recovery will be done in the future. This would be future course of action. I am not referring to past event.

Modal Verbs are used to described abilities , possibilities in the English sentences. Can we use this to describe future events?

I read in some article that It can be use for past/Present and future.

Comment: Can you tell me **if it would be possible for us to recover this amount from him the next month**?We might deduct this amount from his salary next month. OR: Can you tell me: Would it be possible to recover this amount from him?

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentences have some other grammar issues, but **your use of modals is appropriate**.

> Can you tell me how **we could** recover this amount from him in the next month?
>
> Can you tell me **if it would** be possible **for** us to recover this amount from him in the next month?
>
> We might recover this amount from him in his next **month's** salary.

These describe future events.